# Content beween curly braces not rendering Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm tryng to set up a page using angular, and I am having a problem displaying json i recieve from the server.

This is the code:

HTML

```
<body ng-app="App">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item btn-group">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Asignaturas
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<main class="container">
    <div ng-controller="cnt-asignaturas">
        <div ng-repeat="asignatura in asignaturas">
            <p>A {{"Thing"}}</p>
            <p>{{asignatura.nombre_asignatura}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

On which i use angular only at the end, where i have the controller.

Angular

```
var App = angular.module("App",[]);
App.controller("cnt-asignaturas", ["$scope", "$http", function(s,h){
var url = "controladores/getSubjects.php";
s.asignaturas = [];
h.get(url)
 .success(function(data){
    s.asignaturas = data;
    console.log(data);
 }).error(function(error){});
}]);
```

It shows this
[image: It shows this]

And the json
[image: This is the logged json]

I consluded that the problem is that it does not evaluate the braces, but I'm not proficient enough to tell, as I'm doing this mainly to learn.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the json we can test this with?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Not being able to see `A {{"Thing"}}` means that it's probably not really an issue with your controller's code.

Comment: what are you seeing when the html renders?

Comment: Is it Ok to use s instead of $scope?

Comment: Of course charlietfl, here you go: 

[{"nombre_asignatura":"TIM English"},{"nombre_asignatura":"LogÃ­stica de Almacenamiento"},{"nombre_asignatura":"FormaciÃ³n y OrientaciÃ³n Laboral"},{"nombre_asignatura":"InglÃ©s"},{"nombre_asignatura":"GestiÃ³n de Comercio Internacional"},{"nombre_asignatura":"GestiÃ³n EconÃ³mica y Financiera"},{"nombre_asignatura":"Transporte Internacional de MercancÃ­as"}]

That is the response of the server.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 49.0.1. What I see is the "A A A A" thing, it renders neither the json nor a simple string put directly between the braces. It's okay to use s instead of $scope as long as you specify the directives and then pass them to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work (see below or in the plunkr), what version of angular are you using?

**Here is the HTML**

```
<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="App">
<main class="container" >
    <div ng-controller="cnt-asignaturas">
        <div ng-repeat="asignatura in asignaturas">
            <p>A {{"Thing"}}</p>
            <p>{{asignatura.nombre_asignatura}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the controller, I mocked the data.**

```
var App = angular.module("App",[]);
App.controller("cnt-asignaturas", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope,$http){
  $scope.hello = "hello world";
$scope.asignaturas = [{nombre_asignatura: "data 1"},{nombre_asignatura: "data 2"},{nombre_asignatura: "data 3"},{nombre_asignatura: "data 4"}];
}]);
```

**Here is a link:** http://plnkr.co/edit/O1u3RGIFMP0t87qwTDLh?p=preview

Comment: I't worked this morning without changing anything. Maybe it was the browser acting funny